# Is EntLib considered a plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, enterprise-library

Is entlib considered a plugin (specifically the designer via right click on app/web.config)?

I'm downloading/installing VS 2010 Express and I use EntLib 4 already with VS 2008 STD and I'm hoping that I'll still be able to use it with VS 2010 Express. I'd hate to have to go to manually editing the entlib config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the designer part is an extension/plugin, although I have not tested it.

But you can always use the stand alone tool to edit the files. It is the same UI, you just have to start it from windows explorer (right click, then open with).

It is not quite as good as having it integrated, but it is better than editing the files manually.

Answer (score 1):

The integrated config tool in VS2010 is just a bootstrapper that calls the same standalone UI.